# Speech disabilites for PhD admission for international applicants

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, disability

One of my Iranian friends wants to apply for a PhD program in computer science to a US university. He can't speak fluently even in our native language at all, but in the other side he has a relatively strong background:

- Good GPA in both MSc. and BSc. (> 18 out of 20)
- First rank in BSc.
- Graduated from most prominent university in Iran ([Sharif Univ. of Tech.](http://www.sharif.edu/web/en))

**Question:** is there any chance for his application to be approved and for him to get funded?

Note that my question is a little general. I'm not considering a particular university. What I am looking for is how much is it possible for a PhD student to *not* participate in presentations, lectures, team works, typically all works in which he should speak.

In the other hand, I've listed below what he can do perfectly.

- Teacher assistant for lower level students (designing exams, assignments, marking exams/quizzes papers, but not presenting at classroom)
- Review scholarly articles/papers
- Generally all regular jobs that a normal PhD student can do (excluding speech presentations and such assignments)

Comment: I guess one issue would be that many U.S. universities require the TOEFL; he'll have to make sure that they actually read his application and don't summarily reject him for low/missing TOEFL scores. I wonder how best to achieve this?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment, Yes you're right, he should pass TOEFL, but I as far as I know ETS organization have some options for disability accommodations. Maybe it's possible to customize his TOEFL test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided he is fluent in written English, I cannot see how his application could legitimately (or legally) be discriminated against. If he can listen to a spoken conversation without problems, that will hugely decrease the concessions needed to accommodate his disability.

Provided he can *listen* to spoken English without a problem, I do not see why even giving presentations is an unreasonable expectation either. Why not do so in the style of Stephen Hawking, setting to the presentation slides a pre-prepared monologue that is read out by a speech synthesizer? If he is a reasonably fast typist, responding to questions should not be a significant problem either.

This style of communication could even be extended to taking tutorial classes, networking at conferences, etc. Sure, it's a bit awkward and people may take a little while to adjust. But it certainly seems doable.

*Perhaps this is relevant reading: [Is it possible for people with a stutter to have a career in academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38831/is-it-possible-for-people-with-a-stutter-to-have-a-career-in-academia)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I've already read that question you've pointed to, but I think my question is a bit more specific than that one. Yes his *listening* skill, in my opinion, is very good.

Comment: [Stephen Hawking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking) is a very well known cosmologist, who suffers from motor neurone disease. He lost his ability to speak a few decades ago, and now communicates with one cheek muscle.

Comment: _I cannot see how his application could legitimately (or legally) be discriminated against_ — **I can.**  My university requires a TOEFL speaking score of 24 for any international student to be a teaching assistant, and my department requires all PhD students to hold a TAship before they graduate.  As a result, we very rarely admit anyone with a TOEFL speaking score below 20, and all such students are expected to raise their score to at least 24 within their first year. (1/2)

Comment: All that said, _if the applicant revealed their speech disability_ and their record was otherwise strong, I assume we would admit them and provide accommodation. (The department where I got my PhD, which also had a TA requirement, made similar accommodations for a fellow PhD student with severe cerebral palsy.) (2/2)